# On what parameter '==' decides equality?

Tags: java, operator-keyword

When we write the following code in Java:

> > object1 == object2;

on what basis does the operator '==' decide equality?

Comment: http://google.com/?q=java+equality+operator

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[Comparing strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833538/comparing-strings-in-java)** and **[Strings in Java : equals vs ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281448/strings-in-java-equals-vs)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [java == vs Equals() confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `object1` and `object2` are *reference types*, then `==` checks if `object1` and `object2` are both references to the same object.

See [15.21 Equality Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) in the Java Language Specification for full details.

Answer (score 3):

**object1 == object2;** will return true if both are **reference to same object**. Don't assume that it will return true if both objects has same contents or both are objects of same class, etc.

**True** when both references to same object, **false** otherwise.

Comment: You mean **are both references to the same object**. They are different references.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
System.out.println(a==b); //not the same
Object c = new Object();
Object d = c; // d points to the same reference
System.out.prinlnt(c==d); // the same
```